# Validation error yii2

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I have encounter this problem I'm setting fields in the model as unique. Below is my model:

```
[['user_id'], 'unique'],
[['country_id'], 'unique'],
```

And in my controller

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
}
```

unique validator will display. But when I change my controller as:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $model->country_id = 3;
    $model->save();
}
```

My application didn't display the validator. Instead it says it save.

It is a bug from yii2 or I did something wrong here.

Thank you.

Comment: In your second condition, if the `$model->save()` returns `false`, what are you going to do?

Comment: I want to display a validation below field. just like required validation do. thank you

Comment: change `$model->save()` to `if ($model->save() {return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id])})` and keeps other unchange

Comment: yeah that's the only thing I did. I don't know if there's other way to achieve unique validation even modifying save from controller. thank you for your time

Comment: This is not about the `unique validation` at all. This is about your program logic. The `$model->validate()` will run when you call `$model->save()`. If the validate fail, `$model->save()` will return `false`. But your code failed to deal with this situation.

Comment: I'd already check that. but sad to say the code in controller was the only thing that I'd modify. and validation didn't perform.

Comment: What do you mean "validation didn't perform"? Could please add this statement `var_dump($model->getErrors())` just below `$model->save()`, then post what it is?

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
   $model->country_id = 3;
   if($model->validate() == true){
      $model->save();
   }
   else{
      $error = $model->getErrors();
   }
}
```

`$error` will return errors from model.

Answer (score 0):

If  you have error in validation for the modified  model then  $model->save() should return false
so you could check this condition for show a proper message form (or manage properly this situation)

```
  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
  $model->country_id = 3;
  if (!$model->save()){
      return $this->render('yoru_message_form');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. but I'd already tried that. I want to display validation message under the field when it exist.

Comment: If you are in action (this part of code)  ..then mean that you have already send the data to server and you are not more in client form.. in this case you can only  render the model that the user have send  and you have modified with a proper error messge  eg rerendiring the model